# Modelling with a cumulative F-distribution function

Tags: probability-distributions, mathematical-modeling

I'm not a mathematician, so apologies beforehand as the vocabulary/expertise I might display in this enquiry might be a bit sketchy.

I have the following data for a reaction describing the growth of a compound:

[image: data]

The first derivative of this S-shaped curve describing the reaction seems to resemble an F-distribution curve. In my understanding, a cumulative distribution function (CDF) is an integral of a distribution curve, thus I was hoping to fit a CDF like F (10,10) to fit and model my reaction 1 (resembling the bottom right function of the image attached below).

[image: cdf]

Thus, I wanted to ask: what kind of formula could I use in i.e. python to model and obtain parameters of such an S-shaped curve? In this case, what would be the physical meaning of such a reaction with a CDF F-distribution behaviour compared to a reaction with a general logistic function behaviour?

Thanks a lot for the help!!

Comment: I erased the tag "model-theory". This tag doesn't mean what it sounds so your question would sound off topic there

Comment: And I removed the tag "distribution-theory" which is about generalized functions, not statistical distributions.

Comment: A lot of bell-shaped densities on the positive reals have a S-shaped CDF like the $F(10,10)$ example in your bottom right.  It would be the wrong approach to say that you like the look of the shape and then try to find the parameters which fit your reaction data and then try to give physical meaning to them (why use an $F$ distribution rather than for example a gamma distribution?): better to consider your reaction dynamics and then choose a type of distribution based on that.

Comment: Hi @Henry. Maybe I wasn't completely clear in my post. The use of a CDF like the F (10,10) is an assessment based on my reactions dynamics already. Such a conclusion was achieved by, for example, doing the first derivative of my S-shaped reaction. The first derivative of this S-shaped curve follows neither a normal distribution, gamma distribution, etc. What I meant by "perfectly described by a CDF like the F (10,10) was that it's an observation based on the first derivation of my bell curve

Comment: Maybe, but I would have thought the CDF was the integral of the bell curve density rather than its derivative.  An $F$ distribution has two parameters (the degrees of freedom of the underlying $\chi^2$ distributions), the second of which might for example be found using the mean of the distribution: $d_2=\frac{2\mu}{\mu-1}$, though this is less use when you want to scale the $F$ distribution

Comment: @Henry you're right, in my understanding, a CDF is an integral of a distribution curve. What I meant by "first derivative" is the derivative of the S-shaped curve describing my reaction. The first derivative of an S-shaped curve can be described by a distribution function. It's this distribution curve that displays an F-distribution pattern. Therefore, I was hoping to fit a CDF F-distribution model to my S-shaped curve, as its first derivative is a F distribution. I have added a picture to my date to exemplify my case. Maybe it will help to clarify my meaning.

Comment: @Henry I have edited/written the post in a more clear way!